# The inspect function not found

Tags: r, arules

```
Coursetopics <-read.csv("Coursetopics.csv")

#remove first column

Coursetopics.mat <-as.matrix(Coursetopics[,-1])

#convert the binary incidence matrix into a transaction database

Coursetopics.trans<-as(Coursetopics.mat, "transactions")
inspect(Coursetopics.trans)
```

This is the code. My issue is getting the `inspect` function to work properly Error reads as follows:

> Error in inspect(Coursetopics.trans) : could not find function "inspect"

I have added `arules` and `tm` packages but no luck on getting rid of the error.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Mr.Flick-- Thank you for looking at this. I am trying to run an apriori algorithm and I can't get past this error message. I have added ARULES package and a few others, even looked for it on google and in CRAN- no luck. The question is : Do you or anyone else have any ideas on this and how I can get around it , or make the systems work properly??

Comment: Have you run `library(arules)` ?

Comment: I just did got a warning message about arule being built under  R 3.6.3

Comment: That warning shouldn’t really matter. But you could always update Your version of R. Though jumping to 4.0 will require you to reinstall your packages.

Comment: update the version ... go through all the packages... Hmmmmmm.. I choose root canal !  Tank you for the help ! It is very appreciated!